# Invoke-Command using scriptblock not working on remote machine

Tags: powershell, invoke-command

**When using command below, this runs fine when executing an msi package, but now using the same exact command to remotely execute an .EXE, nothing is executing.  If I run this manually from the local machine it works fine.  This executes without error but no results on the $Computer machine.  I validated my script copied the file into the C:\Temp folder.**

```
$Output = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock {"c:\temp\silentinstaller.exe $arg"}
```

$arg contents: /S /TOKEN=''

Comment: You need to supply local variables to a scriptblock using the `-ArgumentList` switch

Comment: Alternatively, use `$using:arg` to remote the variable contents to the scriptblock.